# How do I print two A5 documents on one A4?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microphone

I found lots of advice on how to scale an A4 down to A5 and have two per A4 page. I have one A5 document that I want to print two copies of on an A4 page.

I don't think it's that relevant, because I believe in working toward a higher quality language, where you tell me what to do on "A printer", and I find its way of doing what you describe, but I'm using an Epson Stylus SX235W with MS-Word 2013.

Answer (score 7):

Choose File -> Print. Select "Two page per sheet" and then press Print.

Comment: It's not so simple, e.g. I have a page border on the A5 that now wraps the whole A4, and alignments to page sides etc. all for a loop. I think it will be easier to fix the layout by taking an image, or PDF, and printing two of them per page.

Comment: @ProfKaos, if the layout is a problem you could try adjusting the margins, or even better yet, convert the page into A4 and use the two text column layout.

Comment: Yes, I think converting the page to A4 is the smoothest way for now. Everything else I try, it halves the size of the A5, and prints 2 in an A5 size on the A4 paper.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it's easier to convert (or Save As) the document to PDF at **full size**, which in this case would be A4. Then print from that.

In my experience PDF offers you far more options than most of the MS Office Suite, although I don't have 2013, so I can't say for sure. I often print handouts, and PDF > Landscape > 2 Copies Per Page works for me every time. In your case, I think the border is causing the issue.

Comment: I specifically want the documents in A4 size. My workaround is to physically paste two onto an A4 and scan that.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Word 2000. I regularly print A4 pages shrunk to two A5 pages on a single A4 landscape sheet. These are the steps:

Select:

1. Page Setup - Set Paper size to A5 and the orientation to Portrait
2. Print - This may vary with the Printer. 
          Mine is a Samsung CLP-620.
   (a) In its Properties, select Landscape
   (b) Pages per sheet - select (2)
   (c) Scale to page size - select A4

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use Microsoft Publisher because you can choose a layout where you can put two A5 pages on to one A4 pages. I was having the same problem- the option would be booklet layout

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it's not possible to print two full-size A5 sheets on A4.
That's because there's an unprintable margin where the sheet is pinched and pulled.
The A5 pages have to be scaled down to fit (and the margin trimmed out).

There is a trick, however.
That's first printing the bottom half of the sheet (where there is no margin).
Then turning the sheet over to print the other half (let dry first).
By whatever means your program or hap can use, explained elsewhere.

Most A5 documents can be cropped down to fit by 2 on an A4 sheet in one print.
But that's ugly doing for photographs.
A4 = 21 cm x 29,7 cm = 2x2×10,5×14,85 ≃ 4×10×15 = 4 photos.
The above turn-over method can be used to print 4 10×15 photos on one A4.
At the cost of cropping or shrinking each photo by a mere 0.75 mm in height.

Devised in Wallonia.

Answer (score 0):

**MS Word** actually does provide you with **all the necessary tools onboard**:

In the [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/MlCUiw85C7s) you can see the following step-by-step instruction visually:

1. Go to "File" > "Print"
2. Use the following print settings:

   - Orientation: Portrait (default)
   - Paper size: A5 (default)
   - Pages per sheet: 2
   - Scale to paper size*: A4

*The "Scale to Paper Size" option is available within the "Pages per Sheet" setting

Answer (score -2):

Choose "Open PDF" in Preview from the PDF dropdown in the bottom left of the print dialogue. From there printing options start to make sense.

Comment: As it stands it's quite hard to understand your instructions. Could you edit to clarify? Possibly a screenshot?