# Word 2010: Print 2 A5 documents per A4

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I need to mirror an A5 document onto 2 halves of an A4 piece of paper. How can I do this in Word 2010 and maintain matching margins on each sheet. I found a way of doing it previously, but the 2 A5 documents had different margins. Thanks guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print two A5 documents on one A4?](https://superuser.com/questions/705976/how-do-i-print-two-a5-documents-on-one-a4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [this](http://blog.prominenthosting.com/2009/02/10/how-to-print-one-a4-page-as-two-a5-pages-in-microsoft-word/) solution, try it out:

[image]

All you need to do, in the Print dialog box, is change the ‘Page Range’ from All to Pages: 1,1. Remember to keep ‘Pages per Sheet’ set to 2. Your A4 page is now perfectly printed as 2 A5 pages, side by side on a single A4 sheet.

Comment: Good find, I've printed it to BullZip and looks good... I'll post again and let you know if it's as good on paper :D Thanks!