# Printing 2 x A5 onto one A4 in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, printer

I have tried the various solutions to this and have managed to get from only one A5 doc on A4 to 2.  However, the problem is that the A5 docs are tiny.  I have tried numerous different settings and the size varies from about 25% to around 60% of what it should be.  I'm currently using Word 2013 on my laptop with an Epson printer but I have tried using Word 2010 on an Oki and it doesn't seem to make much difference.

I have these settings:

1. In Word - doc size is A5 and layout is Portrait
2. In Print - Pages 1,1 (to get 2 the same on the page), Orientation Landscape, Paper A4, pages 2 per sheet.

I feel it must be something basic to do with scaling but when I have print preview the A5 seems to show as filling top to bottom in Landscape on left hand side of page but when it prints out it is really small.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Normally, when I have the same issue I save it as PDF. Then with Acrobat Reader is easier to fit x pages per sheet in A4 or other any other format. Just select Print and search for "Multiple Pages Per sheet". Also you have the preview on the same window for test it before printing as in Office.

Comment: Thank you. I also found a way to do it in Word by trial and error.  Similar to above but in Print menu - select Portrait, paper A5 and then scale to A4 and select 2 per sheet and this works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print two A5 documents on one A4?](https://superuser.com/questions/705976/how-do-i-print-two-a5-documents-on-one-a4)

Answer (score 7):

After searching for the answer to this, I couldn't find it so I worked it out with trial and error. Hope this helps someone. Create your document as A5 landscape (using the Layout tab on the Ribbon). Then File -> Print -> Page Setup -> Orientation: Portrait and Multiple Pages: 2 pages per sheet. Back to document, change page size to A4 using Layout -> Size (on the Ribbon). Then File -> Print -> Pages: 1,1 (type "1,1" into the box) -> Print.  Done.  Long winded I know, surely there must be an easier way, but this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me without shrinking the text down was:

1. layout→orientation→portrait.
2. layout→size→A5.
3. file→print→2 pages per sheet.
4. file→print→Pages: 1,1.

Answer (score 0):

Salam
http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?p=405761

So: you'd have to go to page setup: 2 on 1: landscape(in case it's portrait): page size-->a5: output size ---> a4: click on ok: below 'print all pages' type 1,1 in word 2016

Answer (score 0):

Create your document as normal. No need to change it from A4. By changing it to A5, you are making your end document unnecessarily smaller. Print 2 pages to a page, page numbers will be 1,1. if it was a landscape document I think you need to change to portrait for when you print and vice versa.....hopefully I haven’t missed anything